# Jacobian of a transformation

Tags: matrices, tensors, jacobian

I am having problems finding the Jacobian matrix of a transformation in a exercise assigned by my professor. I was wondering if anyone could help me solve this problem:

> Suppose a contravariant tensor $A^i$ in space $\mathbb{R^2}$ where $A^i=(q_{2},q_{1})$ in $q_{i}$ coordinates. Calculate $\overline{A^i}$ in $\overline{q_{i}}$ under the transformation $\overline{q_{1}}=(q_{2})^2$ and $\overline{q_{2}}=q_{1}q_{2}$. Obtain the Jacobian matrix of the transformation.

My main problem is that I am not sure how to apply the Jacobian to this problem. I am confused about how to write the equation of $\overline{A^i}$ so that I may take the partial derivatives.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @CrSb0001 Sorry. My problem is that I am not sure how to apply the Jacobian matrix to this problem. How exactly do I write the equation of $\overline{A^i}$ so that I may take the partial derivatives. I will add this to the question

Comment: So $\overline{A^i} = (\overline{q_1} , \overline{q_2})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello MathLearner and welcome to math here at stackexchange!

A contravariant vector is a type (1,0)-tensor. Using any of the standard setups one can show that the components, $A^j$, of this tensor transform according to the law

$$\bar{A}^i=\frac{\partial \bar{q}^i}{\partial q^j } A^j\tag{1}$$

Sometimes this is even used as the defining property of the quantities $A^j$, especially in older literature.

Clearly the values of $q^j$ and $\bar{q}^j$ must somehow be related. Usually a compressed notation is used:

$$\bar{q}^j=\bar{q}^j(q^h)\tag{2}$$
with inverse
$$q^h=q^h(\bar{q}^j)\tag{3}$$

In your specific case you have
$$\begin{align}\bar{q}^1&=(q^2)^2\\
\bar{q}^2&=q^1q^2\end{align}$$

$$\frac{\partial \bar{q}^i}{\partial q^j }=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial \bar{q}^1}{\partial q^1} & \frac{\partial \bar{q}^1}{\partial q^2}\\ \frac{\partial \bar{q}^2}{\partial q^1} & \frac{\partial \bar{q}^2}{\partial q^2} \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&2q^2\\q^2 & q^1\end{pmatrix}$$

The Jacobian of the transformation $(2)$ is

$$J=\frac{\partial(\bar{q}^1,\dots,\bar{q}^n)}{\partial(q^1,\dots,q^n)}=\det\left(\frac{\partial \bar{q}^i}{\partial q^j}\right)=-2(q^2)^2$$

With $A^j=(q^2,q^1$)

$$\bar{A}^i=\frac{\partial \bar{q}^i}{\partial q^j } A^j=\left(2q^1 q^2, (q^1)^2 + (q^2)^2\right)$$

Note that the question wants you to express this in $\bar{q}^i$ rather than in $q^j$ which is left as an exercise.